# Trying to calculate cohen's d for numeric variables in my dataframe, using a binary variable, what is going wrong?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe which includes participants from two groups, as well as several numeric values with their standardised results. I'm looking to calculate cohen's d and students t for each variable. 
(I know conducting multiple t-tests is not good practice, however in this context it's alright).

Im using the `cohen.d` function in the `psych` package, however whenever I try call the function I get the following error

```
Error in psych::cohen.d(cohen_df, cohen_df$LOWvsHigh, alpha = 0.05,  : 
  object 'group.in' not found
```

**Data:**

```
set.seed(24)
cohen_df <- data.frame(
  LOWvsHigh = sample(0:1, 24, replace = TRUE),
  v1 = rnorm(24),
  v2 = rnorm(24),
  v3 = rnorm(24)
)
```

I then specify this dataset, along with the grouping variable `cohen_df$LOWvsHigh` in the function:

```
cohen.d(cohen_df, cohen_df$LOWvsHigh, alpha = 0.05, std = TRUE, dictionary = NULL)
```

However I get the error specified above, along with the following additional warnings:

```
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In cor(diffs, use = use, method = method) :
  the standard deviation is zero
2: In cov2cor(xvals$rwg) :
  diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful
3: In cor(new.data[, (nvar + 1):ncol(new.data)], diffs, use = "pairwise",  :
  the standard deviation is zero
```

Taking a closer look at the code in the function, it seems my grouping variable is failing the first test, as it isn't length 1 and is not found in the colnames of my dataframe, however I'm not sure how to change it to make it conform to these criteria while still being a grouping variable.

```
function (x, group, alpha = 0.05, std = TRUE, dictionary = NULL) 
{
    cl <- match.call()
    if ((length(group) == 1) && (group %in% colnames(x))) {
        group <- which(colnames(x) %in% group)
        group.in <- TRUE
    }
...
```

Any help is massively appreciated, and if you have other suggestions they're welcome too.

I've tried using t.test, however calling each variable individually is tedious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't have a solution, but encountered the same problem. Used this package instead and it worked: [effsize](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effsize/effsize.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem multiple times using the cohen.d() function from the **psych** package. Load the **effsize** package with the same cohen.d function and you'll be able to use it.